# Put dropdown box and image link in table

Tags: php, html, dropdownbox

```
    <html>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            table,th,td{
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}
            th,tr {
                text-align: center;
            }
            table {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 75%;
            }
            th, td {
                padding: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </html>
    <?php
include 'dbLink.php';

include 'navi.php';


$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
$query = "SELECT * FROM employeerole ORDER BY role_id";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($rowcount > 0) 
{?>
```

How do I input a drop down list and a image link in each table row? Also, when i run this page, only the data in the first row is reflected in the table. The rest of the data is not in the table. Any fixes?

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Employee Role</th>
                <th>Edit role</th>
                <th>Delete User</th>
            </tr>
        <?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {?>
        <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["first_name"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["last_name"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["username"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["role"];?></td>
                    <td>//dropdwon list with data from employeerole table</td>
                    <td>//image link</td>
                </tr>
                 </table>
    <?php}?>

<?php 
}
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Be more specific with your problem.

Comment: two opening `<html>` tags, in one question! I have not seen such a thing before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed `Object Oriented Style` & `Procedural Style` for writing query. So, be particular about *Object Oriented* or *Procedural way* of writing query.

I've written a code for you in both way. Go Ahead.

**1) Object Oriented Style**

***dbLink.php***

```
<?
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
?>
```

***Edited Code***

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
$query = "SELECT * FROM employeerole ORDER BY role_id";

$result = $link->query($sql);
$result1 = $link->query($query);

$rowcount = $result->num_rows;

if ($rowcount > 0) 
{?>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Employee Role</th>
                <th>Edit role</th>
                <th>Delete User</th>
            </tr>
        <?php 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {?>
        <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["first_name"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["last_name"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["username"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["role"];?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
    <?php}?>
    </table>
<?php } 

else
{
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

**2) Procedural Style**

***dbLink.php***

```
<?
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
?>
```

***Edited Code***

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
$query = "SELECT * FROM employeerole ORDER BY role_id";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($rowcount > 0) 
{?>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Employee Role</th>
                <th>Edit role</th>
                <th>Delete User</th>
            </tr>
        <?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {?>
        <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["first_name"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["last_name"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["username"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["role"];?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </table>
<?php } 

else
{
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

**User's Requirement : Updated Code**

```
<?
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($rowcount > 0) 
{?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Employee Role</th>
            <th>Edit role</th>
            <th>Delete User</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["first_name"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["last_name"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["username"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["role"];?></td>
            <td>//dropdwon list with data from employeerole table</td>
            <td>//image link</td>
        </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
<?php 
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: after i change the code to the second style , it only shows one row of data in the table.the rest is not in the table ? any way to fix that? could it be the loop?

Comment: Update your question with your changes @AnniePng

Comment: Why `</table>` is closed inside`while loop`. Please copy as it is @AnniePng. In screenshot, 2 rows are coming. One row in table. Other not in table. Please remove `</table>` from inside while loop and place outside while loop as i've given.

Comment: And, let me know what happened @AnniePng

Comment: Its still the same . :/ @NanaPartykar  .Thats i thot putting it outside the loop helps.yea ..only one row is reflected in the table.

Comment: So, only 2 rows are there . Ok. Means data coming right. @AnniePng. Only first row coming in table and rest not coming. Is it. ? Please reply fast.

Comment: Yes data is coming . just tht the first row is in the table and rest is not .

Comment: You have done some where mistake. Because. Whatever code i've given you. It's working fine. I don't know from where extra `}` coming here in this `<?php 
}
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}
?>` Unless and untill you close proper tag. It will not work. @AnniePng. Try yourself. You have done mistake there. You have not copied code as it is.

Comment: Just in case this gets unnoticed: There is no problem in mixing OOP or procedural style with *mysqli*  it supports both interchangeably.

Comment: Hi @AnniePng : See, I've made all possible changes Now. Please Look On My **User's Requirement : Updated Code** Section. Just Copy It & Paste. You Will Not Get Any Error. *Merry Christmas* *Cheers !!*